# C# Reflection return method content as Delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, reflection

I am working on an ability system that has pre written functions in the Abilities class and handles also Runtime methods, so I use delegates for lambda expression as well.
Obviously I need to call the pre written methods using Reflection.

I use a delegate that wraps a method:

```
public delegate void AbilityAction();
```

The Abilities class contains all the Ability-Methods.

I want to make the following section static:

```
var mi = Abilities.instance.GetType ().GetMethod (abilities[i].name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) as MethodInfo; 

AbilityAction code = (AbilityAction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(AbilityAction), this, mi);
```

And then call it:

```
AbilityAction code = GetMethodInClass(abilities[i].name /*e.g. MegaJump*/, Abilities, AbilityAction);
```

I have tried my best but it gives me errors:

this

A constraint cannot be special class `System.Delegate'

```
public static Delegate GetMethodInClass<T, D>(string methodName, T sourceClass, D delegateType) where D : Delegate {
    var mi = sourceClass.GetType().GetMethod (methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) as MethodInfo;    
    return (D)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(delegateType), this, mi);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sort of code is pretty grody. Consider if you're not better off using something like `dynamic`, or passing expression trees rather than strings.

Comment: "I have tried my best but it gives me alot of errors" - what errors did it give you, exactly? and were they at runtime, or at compile-time?

Comment: what method are you trying to create a delegate to? does it match the delegate signature? (plus or minus the target / `this` part, which can be fudged); can we see how `AbilityCode` is defined, and a method you're trying to target?

Comment: finally; is it possible that the only "error" here is passing `this` instead of `sourceClass` as the target instnace? (note: there are a few things that could be *prettier*, but aren't actually errors)

Comment: It is giving me these errors: at return line: Keyword `this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer and Cannot convert type `System.Delegate' to `D'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see what you're *actually* trying to do without the delegate type and example method, but ... reading between the lines as best as I can, here's a similar example that works:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Foo
{

    public int Bar(string whatever) => whatever.Length;
}

delegate int AbilityAction(string name);
static class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var action = GetMethodInClass<AbilityAction>(nameof(foo.Bar), foo);

        int x = action("abc");
        Console.WriteLine(x); // 3
    }

    public static D GetMethodInClass<D>(string methodName, object target) where D : Delegate
    {
        var mi = target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return (D)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(D), target, mi);
    }
}
```

---

Note: if you don't have C# 7.3, the method needs some minor tweaks:

```
    public static D GetMethodInClass<D>(string methodName, object target) where D : class
    {
        var mi = target.GetType().GetMethod(methodName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return (D)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(D), target, mi);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the compiler wont take the D as a Delegate: error CS0702: A constraint cannot be special class `System.Delegate'

Comment: @McMidas that requires C# 7.3; if you don't have C# 7.3, just remove the constraint - it won't *enforce* it, but: it'll work; `where T : class` may be a reasonable compromise

Comment: @McMidas oh, and the last line needs an indirection to make the compiler happy: `return (D)(object)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(D), target, mi);` - note the addition of `(object)` - this basically defers the type-check to the runtime, where-as C# 7.3 (with the `T : Delegate` constraint) is able to confirm it at compile-time

Comment: Works buddy, Thanks a ton!